# 302 Redirect - Intercepting Redirect response and query string

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am looking to read the Redirect details in the middle ware (is there any other place?). Towards this I have created the required middleware, and the break point is hitting the code. However, unable to locate the Redirect details like path and the query string from the httpContext object. I'm been looking into this for the past hour or so, with no luck. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: It's in HttpContext.Response.Headers["location"]

Comment: @ChrisPratt, i had intentionally not shared the code, as the question was not about an issue in the code, rather getting to know where to look in the code, at the same time, I understand the idea of sharing the code could make things easier for others to read the problem.

Comment: @Tratcher, thank you, i cannot believe i missed it :-). BTW, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in HttpContext.Response.Headers["location"]